# Db Schema for custom file navigation with laravel and mysql

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, filesystems, file-management

### The problem

Hi, i want to have a web app on which the user could navigate through a system of directory and subdirectory and download / see the files. ( similar to a  file manager but they have some important limitation for this project [limitation](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/907) )

I want to create a panel in which i can navigate ( through post request ) to the next folder or  download the file and upload file.

There are two **categories** of user :

- user **A** ( can view user A and B files )
- user **B** ( can view only view user B files )

### Possible solution

What if i create a table in such way

--   --- --

**path** -> string -> primary key ( this path is equals to the path in the file system )

**isDirectory** -> boolean

**canViewByUserB** -> boolean

--   --- --

The path field is unique so i cannot have two file with the same name in the same folder.
So, when the panel is create, i search with a post request for a path that doesn't containt " / ", ( maybe with a LIKE statement ?) so it's in the root folder.
If this query retrieve a:

1. directory, if the user click on it, i do a post request and search for a path that start with "nameOfThisDirectory/someString" but it **must not** contain onother **/** ( in this way i retrive the directory child )
2. a file, get request to download the file with the specify path

**EDIT**

To traverse the file system through the db, here the query

```
select  * from file where path REGEXP '^([^/]*[/]){2}[^/]*$';
```

the '2' indicate two /

what do you think of this solution?
With this setup i can easily do some things, such as

1. create a total download number of a file
2. number of visualization on a file
3. easily navigate through the file system
4. apply policies on files ( user a and user b )

**Thanks**, waiting for advice

Comment: If you set some sort of roles/permissions you can easily allow/restrict any controller's action with policy, regardless of table structure.

Comment: @Tpojka yeah but i must have a structure to know if some user can view certain file.

Comment: In controller method where you are viewing/downloading file, you first check if Auth::user() is type of "A" (i.e. can view anyone's file), if so you're good to go. If Auth::user() is type of "B", you have to check if file is user's file. Both things you can do through [Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization). Read whole section and pay attention on [before()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#policy-filters) method where you can allow user "A" to pass.

Comment: @Tpojka thanks but that's not the problem. I know how to do it. I'd like if some other person would tell me if the db scheme was correct

Comment: Reading again. You just need to save file path, not directory though. If user have many files, it is hasMany belongsTo relation in files table (File model) with foreignId of user_id. I'd go with this avoiding that path complex. I hope it shad some light on this.